# Access Javascript properties with equal names

Tags: javascript

is it possible in Javascript to access equal named properties?

example:

```
var myObject = {
"key1": "value1 ",
"myProp" : "after key1",
"key2": "value2 ",
"myProp" : "after key2",
}

var result = '';
for (var prop in myObject) {
    result += "myObject." + prop + " = " + myObject[prop] + "\n";
  }
alert(result);
```

The example returns only the second property 'myProp'. I need both properties and have to find out, if they are after key1 or key2.

You can try this under http://jsfiddle.net/nxJLh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't in the access : the problem is that there's only one property with a given name, so the second definition of the `myProp` property erases the precedent one.

What you could do is store arrays in your properties :

```
var myObject = {
    "key1": "value1 ",
    "key2": "value2",
    "myProp" : ["after key1", "after key2"],
}
```

you could also look for alternate structures :

```
var myObjects = [
     {key: "key1", value:"value1", myProp: "for key1"},
     {key: "key2", value:"value2", myProp: "for key2"}
]
```

but you're the only one able to chose the proper design for your application here.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I was afraid of this. I'm aware of alternate structures. But my object will be created out of a json-String provided by a lib, which i didn't wanted to change. Maybe i do some regex magic with the string, before parsing it to json.

Comment: @Andreas That's a solution too. But note that according to the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), your text isn't really JSON ("The names within an object should be unique").